# Code to check if a row already exist in phpmysql database

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am a beginner. I am creating a **Student Enrollment System** in which a student first have to enter his/her **CNIC number** on the welcome page, and after pressing the **Submit button**, the PHP code should check whether the CNIC number already exists in the table and proceed to the next page. If it already exists, there should be a **warning message** shown to the user, and the use cannot proceed further.  I've set the column to `UNIQUE`, but i want the warning message.

Some Details:
Database: *phpmysql*,
Database name: *dtbs*,
Table name: *cnic*,
Column name: *CNIC* (this table contains only one column)

Please share the code because i am a newbie and don't know any advanced functions of PHP

Comment: Try to insert the CNIC number in try catch block  and if Duplicate value exception occurs then show the warning message

Answer (score 0):

First you can try doing a find query for the CNIC number and if it is found then let the user know. If it comes back empty - then you can add the new record.